# Where to get functional editor for simple code/config editing inside Windows Server Core docker container?

Tags: docker, text-editor, docker-for-windows

I have heard some people use `edit` or `copy con` but is that really feasible way when using https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-windows-servercore images?

Answer (score 3):

you can install choco firstly by following powershell command.

```
Invoke-WebRequest https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1 -UseBasicParsing | Invoke-Expression
```

then you can install nano or vim by

```
choco install nano
choco install vim
```